# Adobe LiveCycle Designer hiding table columns header per script

Tags: pdf-generation, livecycle, livecycle-designer

The table header row is configured to include header row in subsequent pages and my script should unhide one column dynamically.
But it unhides only the header cell on the first page and the content cells (with a loop over all content cells).
How can I achieve that all header row cells for this column are unhidden (on every following pages).

Table structure:

```
Table
-> TableHeader
--> TableHeaderCells
-> TableContent
--> TableContentCells
```

Code at form main:

```
this.frmTable.tblTable.hdrTableHeader.hdrCellX.presence = "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through table header. Try the following code:

```
var fields = xfa.resolveNodes("this.frmTable.tblTable.hdrTableHeader[*]");
for (var i=0; i <= fields.length-1; i++) { 
  fields.item(i).hdrCellX.presence = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your input. But "fields.length" is 1 even though the table has two headers (two pages). So the headerCell on page two isn't visible :-(

Comment: Strange :( I tested this code and it worked for me. If you could share your form I can try to find what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is an event listener  on the header. With your code it would be something like :

```
frmTable.tblTable.hdrTableHeader::initialize - (JavaScript, client)
    this.hdrCellX.presence = "visible";
```

Initialize should be called automatically on the table updates, flowing into a new page...

Comment: With this code the header cell is shown, but not at the correct place. It overlaps the first header cell :-(

Comment: You _may_ have to calculate manually `tblTable.columnWidths`. I had to. With two columns (let's say 10mm and 15mm if shown) it has to be `"10mm 15mm"`. With the first one hidden it would be `"0.01mm 15mm"`. It's not perfect. I wish I had a cleaner solution, but I don't.

Answer (score -1):

I am not exactly sure without creating a form and trying it myself - but I think you need to use the [*] convention.

Something like this:

this.frmTable.tblTable.hdrTableHeader.hdrCellX[*].presence = "visible";

Also - you may need to play with the bindings too if it is hooked to a back-end data source.  Here is an article I wrote on making repeating subform areas work, and how to bind it to an XML schema http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/binding-xsd.html - which deals with similar concepts.

You then need to do your iterative loop over those fields - I think what is throwing your loop off is that you don't have that [*] indicator in place to indicate that there is more than one, that is why it is only returning the one.

Hope that helps - that is my best guess, looking at what you have here.